# Detecting struckout text in a cell using JExcelApi

Tags: java, excel, jexcelapi

I need to detect whether the text within a cell is struck out or not. I'm using this:

```
Cell cc = sheet.getCell("B1");
CellFormat format = cc.getCellFormat();
System.out.println(format.getFont().isStruckout());
```

but I remember I read somewhere that `CellFormat` is deprecated and `CellFeatures` should be used instead. How could one find out whether a text is struck out using CellFeatures?

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I don't think that's true (but cite your source), as CellFormat and CellFeatures don't really have anything in common.

Maybe you were thinking of jxl.CellFormat is deprecated in favor of jxl.format.CellFormat?